# JSF Pop-ups; can I set their location?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, popup

I've been hunting for an answer, but I am something of a Java Neophyte, and may be using the wrong keywords for what I'm looking for.  I'm using JSF (2.0), and attempting to spawn a popup window, defined to a specific location (I.e., Top Left Corner, or X/Y down from it, etc.)  About the only option I see so far is centering it.

Is there any easy way to do this without adding in some outside tool?  An argument when I spawn it?  Or setting it to somehow move itself once created?

Thanks!

Here's a sample of what I'm using now:

```
            <TABLE width="900">
                <tr><td>
                     <input type=button onclick="javascript:openwindow()" value="Add Something via a Popup"> 
                   </td>
                <tr>
            </TABLE>
```

Followed by:

```
function openwindow() 
{ 
    var retRows = window.showModalDialog("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/SpecInfo.jsp",parentRows,"dialogHeight: 500px; dialogWidth: 860px; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; status: no; toolbar: no; resizable: no; scrollbars: no;");
    if( retRows ){
        for( i = 0; i < retRows.length; i++ ){      
            document.getElementById("spec_item_f"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_item_f;
            document.getElementById("spec_item_i"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_item_i;
            document.getElementById("spec_itemb_f"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_itemb_f;
            document.getElementById("spec_itemb_i"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_itemb_i;
            document.getElementById("spec_itemc_f"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_itemc_f;
            document.getElementById("spec_itemc_i"+(i+1)).value = retRows[i].spec_itemc_i;
            parentRows[i] = retRows[i];
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on *how* you spawn the popup. So I'd give some details about that first. Are you using plain JavaScript `window.open()`? Or an overlay dialog with a `<div>`? Or some JSF component? Or magic? After all, it usually boils down to some JavaScript (look, a new search keyword, try "javascript position popup" or something).

Comment: Added code to the above, since it was a little hard to do it in a comment :)

Comment: Sorry, I see nothing. Perhaps you forgot to save the edits?

Comment: Nah; I was adding them and it took longer than I thought it would :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're using [`window.showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog). According to the linked MDC docs you can use `dialogleft` and `dialogtop` options for this. You'll perhaps only remove the `center` option.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that `javascript:` pseudoprotocol is unnecessary. Remove it.